# Regex replace pattern - advanced find plugin for Gedit

Tags: regex, gedit

I'm trying to replace all instances of

```
$offer->variablenames
```

with

```
$offer['variablenames']
```

Is this possible? I'm using advanced find plugin for gedit.

It's just heiroglyphs to me... Would very much appreciate help.
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Find what:

`\$offer\-\>([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)`

Replace with:

`$offer['\1']`

Make sure to have `Regular expression` checkbox checked.

Comment: It's strange, some other app using $1 instead of \1. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what advanced find plugin syntax is. In vim I would use `s/$offer->\(.*\)/$offer['\1']/g`